# Subtract first row in a column from itself and all rows in that column, for all columns but one, in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table where the first column is timepoints (e.g., 0 min, 10 min, etc.), and every other column is different tests with each row having a measurement at each timepoints. (For the microbiologists here: bacterial growth curves in a 96-well plate.) I want to do a background correction by subtracting the time 0 measurement for each column from itself and all others in the column, so that at time 0 every measurement is 0. However, the time column should be unchanged.

```
> input
time    A1  A2  A3
0       1   1   2
10      2   3   3
20      3   5   4
30      4   7   5

>output
time    A1  A2  A3
0       0   0   0
10      1   2   1
20      2   4   2
30      3   6   3
```

I have tried `df$A1 = df$A1 - df$A1[1]`, and while that works, I have 96 columns and that'd get tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you could do :

```
library(dplyr)
input <- input %>% mutate(across(A1:A3, ~. - .[time == 0]))
input

#  time A1 A2 A3
#1    0  0  0  0
#2   10  1  2  1
#3   20  2  4  2
#4   30  3  6  3
```

In base R you can use `sweep` :

```
input[-1] <- sweep(input[-1], 2, unlist(input[input$time == 0, -1]), `-`)
```

**data**

```
input <- structure(list(time = c(0L, 10L, 20L, 30L), A1 = 1:4, A2 = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 7L), A3 = 2:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` by replicating with `col` to make the lengths same before doing the subtraction

```
input[-1] <- input[-1] - input[-1][input$time == 0][row(input[-1])]
input[-1]
#  A1 A2 A3
#1  0  0  1
#2  0  1  1
#3  0  2  1
#4  0  3  1
```

#### data

```
input <- structure(list(time = c(0L, 10L, 20L, 30L), A1 = 1:4, A2 = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 7L), A3 = 2:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```